# Functions taking NTuple as arguments but imposing (static) size constraints, how to define them?

Tags: static, julia

I want to define functions taking NTuples as arguments but with **with size constraints**.

The idea would be to declare something like:

```
foo(x::NTuple{K-1,Int},y::NTuple{K,Int}) where {K} = "ok"
```

However this is not a correct Julia code.

**My question is:** how to define such kind of functions in Julia?

---

*(For illustration purpose only)*: for C++ coders, my question is equivalent to "how to translate this kind of C++ code

```
template <size_t N>
foo(const std::array<int, N-1>& x, const std::array<int, N>& y) 
{ ... }
```

into well formed Julia code."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific case you can do:

```
foo(x::NTuple{M,Int},y::Tuple{Int, Vararg{Int,M}}) where {M} = "ok"
```

as the difference in dimensions is fixed.

In a more general case the only thing I know of is to add a condition inside the function:

```
foo(x::NTuple{M,Int},y::NTuple{K,Int}) where {M,K} = 
    M + 1 == K ? "ok" : throw(ArgumentError("dimension mismatch"))
```

and the conditional check should be optimized out by the compiler (at least in this case it seems to be optimized under Julia 1.0.3).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand. I do not ever know  if the way it is done in C++ is possible in Julia.

Comment: As I have said - I think it is not possible to directly use exactly the same approach as in C++ but I tried to show you possible equivalent ways to do it.